# Ambiguity result in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

There's a query -

```
select ID from table1;
```

This gives result -

```
ID
101
102
103
104
```

When I use the query  -

```
select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2
```

It gives an error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number.

Whereas, when I use the query -

```
select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN ('101','102','103','104')) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2
```

This gives correct result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use the second form.  That seems pretty simple.

Comment: I just used an example here. it's just not 4 values, its 1000s

Comment: Looks like the `ID` in table1 and `ID` in table2 are of a different type. Please add the example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: from the error, this appears to be oracle, not mysql

Comment: Look in table1 or table2 - whichever has ID defined as a string - for ID values that are not implicitly convertible to numbers. Then you need to decide what do to with those; e.g. fix them, delete them, or ignore them for the purposes of this query. How you do that may depend on which table has strings, and which version of Oracle you are using. And possibly whether you have any relevant indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Table2` uses a text (varchar, nvarchar, etc) type for the `ID`, where `Table1` uses `int` for the ID. You should be able handle this by casting one to other, but really the best option here is fixing the table definitions to match (which might also mean changing the application).

Even then, you'll be better off with a `JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS()` query, instead of `NOT IN()`

Comment: I am not sure how to cast it. Could you pls guide me ?

Comment: How will use not exists() here?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is working fine. Please check data type of ID column in both tables. They should match. One might be number and another might be varchar in your tables.

DB-Fiddle:

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table table1 (id int);
 
 insert into table1 values(101);
 insert into table1 values(102);
 insert into table1 values(103);
 insert into table1 values(104);



 create table table2 (id int, STATUS varchar(50));
 
 insert into table2 values(102,'A');
 insert into table2 values(109,'B');
```

Query:

```
 select ID, CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS FROM table2
```

Output:

| ID | STATUS |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | 0 |
| 109 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edbaac9b40175c0c5e778435da1d7bae)*

Comment: Based on the error message, this was determined to be Oracle, not MySql. Mysql is famously lax (non-compliant) about handling data type mismatches compared to other DBs.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have revised my answer. It's working on oracle too.

Comment: hey, tried this. i dont think so its a casting error. i tried with CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (101,102,103,'104), it was working well.

Comment: What's the data type of ID column in both the tables.

Comment: Both are numbers.

Comment: Please check my db-fiddle link.

Comment: Can you provide the result of this query `select * from TABLE1
where CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) is NULL
and ID IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: or just try : `select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;`

Comment: Your second query is working fine. Please check this link:  *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=253d7bf20161fcc679277c894254b660)*

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify my comments in this question.

> Can you provide the result of this query select * from TABLE1 where
> CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) is NULL and ID IS
> NOT NULL;

The only way that I found to reproduce the issue described here is having non-numeric values in table1. (even if at the beginning we are showing 4 numeric values then we are talking about "it's just not 4 values, its 1000s")

### testcase

```
drop table table1;
drop table table2;

create table table1 (id VARCHAR2(100));
 
insert into table1 values(101);
insert into table1 values(102);
insert into table1 values(103);
insert into table1 values(104);
insert into table1 values('MY BAD');

create table table2 (id NUMBER);

insert into table2 values(102);
insert into table2 values(109);


select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (101,102,103,'104')) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;

select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN ('101','102','103','104')) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;

select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (101,102,103,104)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;


select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;

select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;
```

In this test-case, the only query generating an error ORA-01722: invalid number is

```
select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;
```

it corresponds at the behavior described.

This is why my suggestion is to do an implicit cast and avoid the errors as already suggested in this thread

```
select ID, 
    CASE WHEN (ID NOT IN (SELECT CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM TABLE1)) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END STATUS 
FROM TABLE2;
```

and try to find the non-numeric values

```
Select * from TABLE1 where
CAST(ID AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) is NULL and ID IS NOT NULL;
```